# Using named arguments in Javascript with regular expressions as names of arguments

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments, named

Is it possible to use named arguments in Java or Javascript with regular expressions as the names of arguments? I want to make it possible to call a function like this:

```
f("function name:", "drawCircle", "radius:" 1, "xPos:" 0, "yPos:", 0, "color:", "red");
```

Or like this, with exactly the same effect:

```
f("name of function:", "draw a circle", "y position:", 0, "color:", "red", "rad:" 1, "x location:" 0);
```

Both of these should be equivalent to foo(1, 0, 0, red).

In both cases, the arguments that are given should match a list of regular expressions. It should be possible to list the arguments and the function name in any order with the same result.

Is there any way to implement something like this?

Comment: Just to be clear, Java and JavaScript have very little in common. They're completely distinct languages.

Comment: Also don't forget to declare your local (JavaScript) variables with `var`!!

Comment: I'm using the javax.script package, using Javascript within Java. I used Javascript because I prefer working with programming languages that use closures/nested functions.

Comment: @AndersonGreen If your writing javascript within Java then highfive o/ Maybe try a JS -> Java compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f({
  "name": "drawCircle", 
  "radius": 1, 
  "xPos": 0, 
  "yPos": 0, 
  "color": "red"
});
```

This is why you use objects in javascript.

Although you probably want

```
drawCircle({
  radius: 0,
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  color: "red"
});
```

Comment: I want something more like this (in pseudocode, using regular expressions that should be matched by the strings in the constructor). f({
  `/(fun(ction|))(| )(name|nm)/: "drawCircle", 
  /(rad)(|ius)/i: 1, 
  /(xPos)/i: 0, 
  /(y)(| )(pos)(ition|)/i: 0, 
  /color/i: "red"
});`

Comment: @AndersonGreen that sounds completely useless. What's your use case?

Comment: I'm trying to use strings that match specific regular expressions as the names of arguments. Each argument name in the function call should correspond to exactly one regular expression. I'm trying to make it easier to remember the names of the arguments by allowing multiple names for each argument.

Comment: It isn't possible to use a regular expression as a function name or named argument in Javascript, but I'm trying to find a workaround solution.

Comment: @AndersonGreen why don't you spend time on documenting your APIs properly instead?

Comment: What is the "proper" way to document Javascript APIs? Is there a standard, like Javadoc for Java? (It looks like JSDoc is the most popular - maybe I'll start using it.)

Comment: @AndersonGreen write a README.md with examples e.g. https://github.com/Colingo/valid-schema#example

Comment: At first, I was actually trying to improvise my own "literate programming" system in Javascript, but I'm still not sure whether this would really be worth the effort. In this system, `f("replace the array:", arr, "in the array:", arr, "with the array:", arr)` would be equivalent to `f("replace array:", arr, "in array:", arr, "with array:", arr)`. I just wanted to match a series of named arguments to each function so that the functions could be called using more "English-like" syntax.